# Python random sample of two arrays, but matching indices

Tags: python, random, numpy

I have two numpy arrays x and y, which have length 10,000.
I would like to plot a random subset of 1,000 entries of both x and y.
Is there an easy way to use the lovely, compact random.sample(population, k) on both x and y to select the same corresponding indices? (The y and x vectors are linked by a function y(x) say.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) on an index array and apply it to both arrays:

```
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), 1000, replace=False)
x_sample = x[idx]
y_sample = y[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize you could call entries of an array like that x[idx]!

Comment: People using normal arrays and running into "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" might want to use the following: `x_sample = list(np.array(x)[idx])`.

Answer (score 9):

Just zip the two together and use that as the population:

```
import random

random.sample(zip(xs,ys), 1000)
```

The result will be 1000 pairs (2-tuples) of corresponding entries from `xs` and `ys`.

***Update:** For Python 3, you need to convert the zipped sequences into a list:*

```
random.sample(list(zip(xs,ys)), 1000)
```

Comment: In the document, it says it takes only 1 parameter which is _size_. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.sample.html Can you add the link to a document?

Comment: @SanghyunLee - My answer doesn't use numpy. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 1):

After test `numpy.random.choice` solution,
I found out it was very slow for larger array.

`numpy.random.randint` should be much faster

example

```py
x = np.arange(1e8)
y = np.arange(1e8)
idx = np.random.randint(0, x.shape[0], 10000)
return x[idx], y[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `numpy.random.randint` function, you generate a list of random numbers, meaning that you can select certain datapoints twice.